# Google Cloud Run end-user authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm using Google Cloud Run for a simple POC web app. My hope was to lean on GCP IAM to handle authentication for the time being, similar to how Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) can be used in conjunction with App Engine or GKE.

When I gave the Cloud Run Invoker role to a user, I expected authentication to work similar to how IAP does (login redirect auth flow), but I get a 403 error instead. I can curl it setting the `Authorization` header though.

Is it required to implement authentication in the app for user-facing web applications? I was hoping to do a quick prototype by relying on IAM. If it is required, what would be the recommended way to implement OAuth2 authentication for a simple prototype? [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)?

Comment: This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating

Comment: You will need to authorize your own Google OAuth tokens and then add to the HTTP headers.

Comment: The current design of authorization for Cloud Run does not lend itself for websites. Think service to service authorization (APIs).

Comment: Indeed, this is what I'm discovering. I guess my question really is: is Cloud Run actually intended for web applications at all or just "backend" services? It would seem more the latter. I would have expected similar behavior to IAP, especially since the role management has a very similar look and feel.

Comment: Cloud Run works well for websites. Web Applications need clarifying as Cloud Run has HTTP run time limits (timeouts). For normal HTTP Request / Response designs I am impressed. I think that the authorization features might have been rushed to get into beta. I have a feeling that Google will put more work into this area before production status arrives. Providing feedback will probably help them decide on what's critical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run PM here,

Yes, right now you're required to host your own OAuth client, e.g.:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sign-in + Run</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div></br>
    <div>
      <div id="returned-text"></div></br>
      <button id="test">Test</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    var id_token;

    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test').on('click', function () {
        var serviceURL = 'https://...';

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', functionURL);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + id_token);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               $('#returned-text').text(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that CORS will be wonky here, and we recommend hosting on the same origin to get rid of this (e.g. use the [Firebase Hosting integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)).

In the future, it's likely we'll offer IAP (which hosts an OAuth client for you).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @mike's approach I created a Cloud Run hosted version of an Identity Aware Proxy in a Terraform config.

https://futurice.com/blog/identity-aware-proxy-for-google-cloud-run

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) is now available (as a preview) for Cloud Run...

- https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run

And if you want to tweak things there is a sample that shows how to customize the sign in page here:

- https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-run-sign-in

Note: I haven't tried any of this yet (but looking forward to it as an upcoming weekend project)!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve end-user authentication using External Load Balancer with IAP enabled:

- create a Cloud Run service with "Require authentication" options setup
  ingress options to be "Allow internal traffic and traffic from Cloud Load Balancing"
- expose the service using and External Load Balancer with IAP enabled
- give the user the role "IAP-Secured Web App User" for the backend service

You can follow this tutorial to have a working examples [hodo.dev/posts/post-30-gcp-cloudrun-iap/](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-30-gcp-cloudrun-iap/)