# Unable to set up the sign-in for the Cloud Run instance and unable to roll the changes back, lost the access to my Cloud Run URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I tried different official tutorials but they all ended up to be misleading.

The last one was this: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-run-sign-in -- it ​says:

> Enable external identities, and select the **Host a sign-in page for me** option during setup.

But there was no such option. No new Cloud Run instance was created and so nothing has happened. Then after a while I've updated the source code of my application, redeployed and the blue login button appeared on the Cloud Run instance URL instead. NO documentation tell that "on this step you'll now see the blue button" so I don't know for sure what it is. When I went through the dialog it said I should add the Cloud Run instance URL to the "allowed origins" in the OAuth app I created a week ago by trying different tutorials I mentioned in the first place. Aha! I add the URL as allowed but this does nothing -- **it just loops, the dialog leaves me on the same page with the same blue button** instead of my Cloud Run instance response that now I effectively have no access to. I am the GCP Project owner and I want this all to check that it's me to invoke the Cloud Run. **How does this specific OAuth app blocks this specific Cloud Run instance at all?** I have multiple apps made in months or years and multiple Cloud Run instances but only now this blue button appeared.

Being unable to make it work I decided to roll it all back. I allowed the Unauthenticated calls to my Cloud Run instance, disabled the IAP API, deleted the OAuth app, redeployed several times, but the blue button is still there with dialog saying: "The OAuth client was deleted." And I see nothing like my current problem to be described on https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting

So now not only the whole thing didn't work (the "sign-in page" does not deploy, not even if I disable and enable the IAP API again) but **I've lost the access to the Cloud Run** instance at all -- it's blocked by the blue button that is nowhere to disable. Even when I deploy new services they are behind this broken thing.

**UPD:** after a while I've realised that I didn't really lose any access -- the "blue button" was an artifact of the failed tryings to setup the auth, a my own copypasted htm page that didn't work, and I was just visiting the wrong path appended to the service URL. So the question is half-invalid. Though the problem of the "create a sign-in page for me" persists.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, IAP is only supported with App Engine, Compute Engine and HTTPs Load balancers. Cloud Run isn't yet supported. It is planned to be supported in the near future.

As a workaround you can check those two options in order to implement with your application:

1 - A similar [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069543/google-cloud-run-end-user-authentication) where is stated and answer about how to Google Sign in for Cloud Run

2 - A Cloud Run hosted version of an [IAP in Terraform config](https://futurice.com/blog/identity-aware-proxy-for-google-cloud-run) made by the community

Also you can try to [Setup a Load Balancer with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) and see if that solves the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

> Enable external identities, and select the Host a sign-in page for me option during setup.

I believe this is referring to - when you turn on IAP and choose '*use external identities for authorization*', there is an option that says - '*Create a sign-in page for me*' with a note which says - I*AP will create a sign-in page for you using Cloud Run and Firebase UI*

2.
I tried following the steps and after checking the option to 'create a sign-in page for me', it showed me a popup window with a message that it was creating a Cloud Run instance for me. After about 3 minutes, it said it was done and showed me url for the Cloud Run instance and a link to the page settings

3.
Regarding access to the Cloud Run instance, I think it's best to just delete it from the UI (Google Cloud Console). Redeploying will then recreate the Cloud Run service and you should no longer have the 'blue button' since you say you have disabled it

[image]

Comment: I don't see the 'create a sign-in page for me' button anywhere. The https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-run-sign-in leads to https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enable-external-identities there I "Open the IAP page" I select the project and see this https://i.imgur.com/tqL8SE1.png press the button, get this https://i.imgur.com/2mXwH6k.png and get this https://i.imgur.com/c7Q2P3l.png

Comment: Disabled IAP again. Deleted the Cloun Run instance, redeployed. It made "revision-00001". And there is still the blue button.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a screen shot. I'm at a loss for why you can't see it